# Добавить суффиксы всем файлам в директории

Tags: python, linux, bash

У меня есть набор директорий с файлами в корневой директории `test`. Как рекурсивно добавить всем файлам (НЕ директориям) в `test` суффиксы `.txt`?

Например, были директории `test`, `test/a`, `test/b` и файлы `test/x`, `test/b/y`. Как сделать из этого `test/x.txt`, `test/b/y.txt`, при этом сохранив `test/a` нетронутым?

Интересует bash-команда или python-скрипт.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал вот так:

```
find test -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -i "$1" "$1.txt"' _ {} \;
```

На >10 Gb директории с сотнями тысяч файлов и директорий не упало, так что должно быть нормально.

Comment: Не поддерживается идемпотентность.

Answer (score 0):

Немного улучшенная версия:

```
$ find test -type f ! -name '*.txt' -exec mv {} {}.txt ';'
```

Так команда не будет переименовывать файлы, которые уже
с расширением, а также убран лишний вызов
интерпретатора. (Правда, по поводу второго стандарт *POSIX*
говорит, что ответ на вопрос, заменяется ли `{}`
на имя файла в конструкциях типа `{}.txt`, является
«*implementation defined*», но во всех популярных имплементациях
это поддерживается.)